# Background image fading with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, fadein

I have a series of images that cycle through a slideshow as css `background` properties. The code below should also have them fade in and out via jQuery's `fadeIn` property, but for some reason it does not fade, and simply changes instead. Any ideas?

This is a follow up from a comment that was never solved. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5fVZ7/6/

```
var images=new Array();
images[0]='http://s29.postimg.org/912bsm0mf/dataarancio.jpg';
images[1]='http://s27.postimg.org/y6tl17eb7/velocita.jpg';
var nextimage=0;
doSlideshow();

function doSlideshow(){
    if(nextimage>=images.length){nextimage=0;}
    $('.bkg')
    .css('background-image','url("'+images[nextimage++]+'")')
    .fadeIn(500,function(){
    setTimeout(doSlideshow,4000);
});
}
```

Comment: why do you want to reinvent the wheel? There are tons of examples online and even on stackoverflow to achieve same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388118/trying-to-make-multiple-background-images-cycle-through-a-slideshow-with-css-and

Comment: @MikeRoss If I had found a working solution that fit my guidelines I would have used it, thanks. This code is actually much simpler than others that I have found that achieve similar results.

Comment: @Tom There are couple of [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194401/fade-in-and-out-with-jquery-image-gallery) on this question and also look at this [website](http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/) and still if it doesnt work out than edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @MikeRoss Both of your links are to examples dealing with images defined in the html, this question deals with css background images that cover and are fixed, with html content rendered overtop. I appreciate your comments, but i believe i have sorted it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to wrap the `if` statement and `css` property changes in a `fadeOut` fucntion, like so:

```
var images=new Array();
images[0]='http://s29.postimg.org/912bsm0mf/dataarancio.jpg';
images[1]='http://s27.postimg.org/y6tl17eb7/velocita.jpg';
var nextimage=0;
doSlideshow();

function doSlideshow(){
  $('.bkg').fadeOut(500,function(){
    if(nextimage>=images.length){nextimage=0;}
    $('.bkg').css('background-image','url("'+images[nextimage++]+'")');
  });

  $('.bkg').fadeIn(500,function(){
    setTimeout(doSlideshow,4000);
  });
}
```

I think this piece of code is simpler and more effective than many others I've found that do the same thing, including the answer to the duplicate question posted in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

.fadein changes the opacity of the element, but you are making changes to the background image. Animations can only act on numeric values, there's no way for the browser to calculate a background image that is "between" image1 and image2. So instead, try overlaying the images as separate html elements and using fadein to control their visibility in sequence.